# Jmeter for testing rest api

Tags: jmeter

Hi i'm using jmeter to test a restapi.
the test query is http:hostname:port\resource?{parameter}={value}

In this parameter comes from a csv file which contains first column as search parameter and second column as another csv file name or path which contain the values to be filled up in value of query.

how to do that?

eg: csv 1: col1: parameter1 col2: path of csv2
inside csv2: col1: value1, value2, value3

so this is like one to many mapping from every row in csv1 to all rows in csv2

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine you have following files:

1. `1.csv` with the following contents:

   ```
   line 1 from 1.csv,2.csv
   line 2 from 1.csv,3.csv
   ```
2. `2.csv` with the following contents:

   ```
   line 1 from 2.csv
   line 2 from 2.csv
   ```
3. `3.csv` with the following contents:

   ```
   line 1 from 3.csv
   line 2 from 3.csv
   ```

You can achieve your requirement with the following JMeter Test Plan:

- [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

  [image: JMeter Thread Group]

  - [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

    [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

    - [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with the condition defined by [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as:

      ```
      ${__groovy(new File(vars.get('var2')).readLines().size(),)}
      ```

      [image]

      - Your sampler which will be referring variables from the nested CSV file(s) using [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) like:

        ```
        ${__CSVRead(${var2},0)}${__CSVRead(${var2},next)}
        ```

        [image: JMeter CSVRead]

Altogether with demo:

[image: JMeter Nested CSV]

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. This solution is working only when i turn on the recycle on EOF as TRUE. Which means the loop is executing for only one time. And i don't understand what does that loop controller statement do

Comment: The above setup is a "skeleton" to show how you can reference nested files using CSVRead() function, you're free to configure [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)  and [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) according to your test scenario. Loop controller is needed to iterate as many times as the number of rows you have in the nested CSV files (2.csv and 3.csv), otherwise CSVRead function will start over and you will get duplicate data.

Comment: if the input is like {1 {1.1, 1.2}, 2 {2.1, 2.2}} the output i'm getting is like 1-1.1, 2-2.1, 1-1.2, 2-2.2. but i need it like 1-1.1, 1-1.2, 2-2.1, 2-2.2. How to do that

Comment: You need to play with [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) of the CSV Data Set Config and set it according to your scenario. We cannot help further without seeing your Test Plan and at least first 2-3 lines of the CSV files.